# XML Attribute lookup via java bean

Tags: java, xml, parsing, session

I've web.xml where tomcat lookup for value

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I want the same value to be fetched into javabean file as variable.

Is there any better way to lookup on this without actually pasing throuh entire xml file to get just a value.

Does this can be implemented by JNDI lookup ?

Again, TY for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way I think you can do it(though verbose) is to implement your own [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). Override its [sessionCreated()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) method, you can get a reference to the `HttpSession` from the `HttpSessionEvent` and by invoking [HttpSession#getMaxInactiveInterval()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29), you can get the session-timeout value in seconds. You can then store the value in your bean. there will be cons to this solutions, I will update it.